# Relative pronoun or Subordinating Conjunction?

Tags: conjunctions, relative-clauses, relative-pronouns, subordinate-clauses

We know that an **adjective clause** may begin with a relative pronoun :
"This is the song **which my mother taught me**".
Here, **which** is a relative pronoun. But can we regard **which** as *a Subordinating Conjunction* in that it connects the Subordinate Adjective Clause with the Principal Clause? One of my friends say that **which** is a *relative pronoun* here ; but not a *conjunction*. So, I am confused. Please clarify whether **which** is a *pronoun* or a *conjunction* or *both of these*.

Comment: Your friend is right: 'pronoun' and 'subordinator' are distinct parts of speech. A word can't belong to two different parts of speech at the same time. "Which" belongs to the part of speech 'pronoun'.

Comment: Incidentally, I strongly advise you to drop the term 'adjective clause'; it's a misnomer. In your example the subordinate clause is relative one, a modifier, not some kind of adjective.

Comment: @BillJ, could you please tell me the difference between a relative clause and an adjective clause?

Comment: There really is no such thing as an 'adjective clause'. Adjective is a part of speech used to classify words and phrases, but not clauses. Just because something modifies a noun (like adjectives typically do) doesn't mean it's actually an adjective. In any case, non-defining relative clauses are not modifiers, so they could hardly be called 'adjective clauses'.

Comment: @BillJ, I know that. But defining relative clauses are treated as subordinate adjective clauses. In my posted sentence,  the relative clause "which my mother taught me" is a defining relative clause. Therefore, can't it be regarded as a subordinate or depending clause and the relative pronoun "which" as a subordinating conjunction? Could you please clarify it ?

Comment: Yes, a subordinate/dependent clause. Subordinating conjunctions are meaningless markers of subordination, whereas relative pronouns like "which" have a distinct meaning that is derived from an antecedent. In your example, the relative pronoun "which" has "song" as its antecedent. The function of "which" in the relative clause is object of "taught".

Comment: Are you clear now that it is **not** a subordinating conjunction for the reason I gave? Secondly, defining relative clauses are **not** called subordinate adjectival clauses. They are modifiers, as I have already told you.